# Using -classpath on terminal doesn't work

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

When I try using the -classpath option I cannot execute any program.

I can compile it with

```
javac FirstClass.java -cp C:\Users\pierr\Desktop\Isitgonnawork
```

but when executing,

```
java FirstClass -cp .;C:\Users\pierr\Desktop\Isitgonnawork
```

I get this exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StdOut
        at FirstClass.main(FirstClass.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: StdOut
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

This happens when the classpath is a jar file and also when it's a simple directory containing java files.

The strange thing is that when I put the path to the directory/jar file in the CLASSPATH environment on Windows, I can compile & run without problem, but not using the -classpath  option...

I am on Windows.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: *and also when it's a simple directory containing java files.* - Java files need to be compiled, otherwise they won't be executable. You should run `javac` on all your source files before running `java`.

Comment: The `-cp` argument must be before the source filenames in `javac` and the class name and app arguments in `java`.  Please refer to the manual entries for `java` and `javac`.

Answer (score 0):

> The -cp argument must be before the source filenames in javac and the class name and app arguments in java. Please refer to the manual entries for java and javac. – Stephen C

Thanks ! This was indeed what I did wrong.